# how to use multiple react spring bottom sheet?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

hello guys i'm using `react-spring-bottom-sheet` i have a page that should be act as a bottomsheet and inside this page i have another bottom sheet when inside this page i colse second bottomsheet , both bottomsheets are closed, how should I use multiple react-spring-bottom-sheet in one component, in a way that on each swipe down only topper bottomsheet would be closed?

```
  <SpringBottomSheet
      isOpen={open}
      onDismiss={onBottomSheetClose}>
    data and other things of first bottom sheet
 <SpringBottomSheet
      isOpen={open}
      onDismiss={onBottomSheetSecondClose}>
   data of second one
 </SpringBottomSheet>

</SpringBottomSheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add dismiss to upper bottom sheet on close second one , because if a bottom sheet doesnot have onDismiss property, base on the [docs](https://react-spring-bottom-sheet.cocody.dev/) it won't close , so
i add onDismiss conditionally to bottomsheet

```
 <SpringBottomSheet
      isOpen={open}
      onDismiss={isDismisableBottomSheet ? onBottomSheetClose : undefined}></SpringBottomSheet>
```

`isDismisableBottomSheet` will be true after closing second bottomsheet, also it shouldnot be immediate and sould be couple of milisconds after closing upper bottomsheet